# Скроллирование внутри UIView при кастомной отрисовки с использованием Core Graphics

Tags: ios, objective-c, анимация, uiview

Всем доброго времени суток.
У меня есть UIView в ней перекрыто onDraw и прописана кастомная отрисовка - график. Причем график может скроллироваться бесконечно как в лево так и вправо (по времени), жест для смещения вот такой:

```
CGPoint pt = [recognizer translationInView:self];
if(recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
    beginPt = CGPointMake(offset.x + pt.x, 0);

offset = CGPointMake(beginPt.x + pt.x, 0);//используется для отрисовки

[self setNeedsDisplay];

CGPoint velocity = [recognizer velocityInView:recognizer.view];
if(recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
{
    CGPoint startPoint = offset;
    offset = CGPointMake(offset.x  +  (velocity.x / 5.5), 0);
    //как сюда добавить анимацию скроллирования?
}
```

Подскажите как реализовать анимацию, когда смещение останавливается как в стандартном UIScrollView?
Что-то мне подсказывает, что надо заюзать CAScrollLayer, но я не понимаю как это сделать, поскольку у меня отрисовка идет по видимым координатам и получается на главном слое. В общем в слоях не шарю растолкуйте плиз.
Заранее спасибо всем

Comment: Не очень понятна задача. Что мешает просто сдвигать координаты UIView в блоке анимации? Можете привести пример как вы делаете кастомную прорисовку? Если будет какой-нибудь примитивный пример, будет проще ответить на ваш вопрос.

Comment: Если сдвигать UIView, то надо создать еще одну сверху и сдвигать. Но слои сделаны наверно не просто так? А, как я понимаю, для анимации в том числе. Рисование стандартное например для круга - CGContextAddArc. Самое примитивное это в центре вьюхи нарисовать круг, и сдвигать его при помощи когда выше, где offset запоминается. Т е в какой то момент offset, например по х, становится отрицательным или больше ширины экрана это значит, что круг уходит за пределы видимости. И вот для этого надо добавить анимацию инерции.

Comment: Зачем сдвигать UIView, если можно сдвигать координаты ваших кастомных объектов? Если вы сделаете хотя бы самый простой пример (тут или на GitHub), то ответить будет проще.

Comment: [вот пример](https://ru.files.fm/u/tudj7yvn)

Comment: вопрос еще актуален